# Find differences in list of strings

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, group-by, python-itertools

input list:

['A.B.C.D','A.A.C.D','A.B.E.F','A.B.E.GG']

The strings are variables concatenated with a dot. So in first string, variables are A B C D, but in last string variable are A B E GG (variables can be of varying length), but the strings will always have the same number of variables separated by the dot. I would like to group those strings together which have only one different variable. So above would produce 2 groups.

['A.B.C.D','A.A.C.D']
['A.B.E.F','A.B.E.GG']

The the difference has to be in the same variable. not one difference across all variables. and each string should be included only once, not multiple times across groups.

Real data could have up to 20 variables (but all items in each list will always have the same number of variables), and lists could have several minion strings, so performance is also a concern.

I wrote an algorithm which does it but is too complicated. I also tried via itertools groupby but could not get it to produce the correct results:

```
import itertools
import difflib

class Grouper:
    def __init__(self, diff):
        self.last = None
        self.diff = diff
    def get_diffs(self, curr_key):
        if self.last == None:
            return []
        dims = curr_key.split('.')
        previous_dims = self.last.split('.')
        diffs = list((dm for dm in difflib.ndiff(dims, previous_dims) if '-' not in dm and '?' not in dm))
        return [n for n, d in enumerate(diffs) if '+' in d]
    
    def __call__(self, item):
        result = self.get_diffs(item)
        print(item)
        self.last = item
        return result


grp = Grouper(data)
groups = []
uniquekeys = []

for k, g in itertools.groupby(data, grp):
    groups.append(list(g))      # Store group iterator as a list
    uniquekeys.append(k)
```

UPDATE:

More sample input:

['D.1.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.7.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.21.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.15.6.A.1.B.C', 'D.25.6.A.1.B.C', 'D.7.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.8.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.8.6.A.1.B.C', 'D.10.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.14.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.15.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.15.6.A.1.B.C', 'D.16.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.17.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.18.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.19.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.20.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.21.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.22.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.23.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.25.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.25.6.A.1.B.C', 'D.26.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.27.2.A.1.B.C']

Comment: Hmm what if the input list is `['a:1', 'b:1', 'c:1']`? Are these three all in the same group?

Comment: What if you have `"A.B.C.D"` and `"A.B.D.C"` What is the number of differences?

Comment: @j1-lee only if : is used as separator instead of ., otherwise no.

Comment: @DaniMesejo 2 diffs, because both variable 3 and 4 are different

Comment: What if you have: `["A.B.C", "A.B.D", "A.E.D"]`?

Comment: @BeChillerToo you could group it multiple ways (given the description in the question). ["A.B.C", "A.B.D"] OR ["A.B.D", "A.E.D"]. The difference has to be in the same variable, and the same string should not be in more than one group.

Comment: What should be the result then? `["A.B.C", "A.B.D"], ["A.E.D"]` or  `["A.B.C", "A.B.D"], [A.B.D", "A.E.D"]`?

Comment: ["A.B.C", "A.B.D"], ["A.E.D"] OR ["A.B.C"], ["A.B.D", "A.E.D"]. each string can only appear once across groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added another string "A.B.C.F", this string can be matched with "A.B.C.D" and "A.B.E.F":

```
import itertools


def main(l: list) -> list:
    splits = [tuple(s.split(".")) for s in l]

    groups = {}
    # Dict of {(tuple, index of difference): list of tuples that match the key}

    for split in splits:
        matched = False
        for (t, i) in groups.keys():
            # We match two splits if they only have one difference
            diffs = [i for i in range(len(split)) if split[i] != t[i]]
            if len(diffs) == 1:
                # The strings match but is the first match of 't'?
                if i is None:
                    groups.pop((t, i))
                    groups[(t, diffs[0])] = [split]
                    # We found a match, stop the matching of this tuple
                    matched = True
                    break
                elif diffs[0] == i:
                    groups[(t, i)].append(split)
                    matched = True
                    break
        if not matched:
            # Let's add this split as a candidate for future splits
            groups[(split, None)] = []

    return [[".".join(k)] + [".".join(s) for s in v] for (k, i), v in groups.items()]


print(main(["A.B.C.D", "A.A.C.D", "A.B.E.F", "A.B.E.GG", "A.B.C.F"]))
# [['A.B.C.D', 'A.A.C.D'], ['A.B.E.F', 'A.B.E.GG'], ['A.B.C.F']]
print(main(["A.B.C", "A.B.D", "A.E.D"]))
# [['A.B.C', 'A.B.D'], ['A.E.D']]
```

Comment: thank you, almost there but the difference has to be in the same variable. not one difference across all variables. first group: for first 2 tuples the diff is in elem 2, but in the last tuple the diff is in last elem (if if compare first and last tuple in that group). and each tuple should appear only in one group.

Comment: Oooh, ok I see now

Comment: If one tuple could appear in two groups (like my previous comment on your original post), how do you decide which group this tuple should belong? First come first served?

Comment: ideally, I would like to maximize group size, so I can find all elements which could be grouped together based on the same variable. but if the list is sorted, it will probably be the same as first come first served.

Comment: Is is better now?

Comment: jeez that was fast. I am looking now the groups look correct thank you!

Comment: this works but is very slow. it has been running now for an hour on a couple of million strings.

Comment: the list I always pre-sort so it only needs to match to the current group. I will see if I can change it to not work on the global matches but only current.

Answer (score 1):

Solving the [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) using a greedy algorithm:

```py
string_list = ['A.B.C.D','A.A.C.D','A.B.E.F','A.B.E.GG', 'A.B.C.F']
list_list = [s.split('.') for s in string_list]
# [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'A', 'C', 'D'], ...]

universe = set(range(len(string_list)))
# {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
# represents string_list by index
# for instance, 3 represents 'A.B.E.GG'

subsets = {frozenset(j for j,l in enumerate(list_list) if l[:i]==l0[:i] and l[i+1:]==l0[i+1:]) for l0 in list_list for i in range(len(l0))}
# {{2}, {2, 3}, {0, 1}, {0, 4}, {3}, {2, 4}, {1}, {4}, {0}}
# represents possible groupings by index
# for instance, {2, 3} represents {'A.B.E.F', 'A.B.E.GG'}

solution = []
while universe:
  max_subset = max(subsets, key=len)
  solution.append(max_subset)
  universe -= max_subset
  subsets.remove(max_subset)
  subsets = {subset & universe for subset in subsets}

print(solution)
# {{2, 3}, {0, 1}, {4}}

clusters = [[string_list[i] for i in subset] for subset in solution]
print(clusters)
# [['A.B.E.F', 'A.B.E.GG'], ['A.B.C.D', 'A.A.C.D'], ['A.B.C.F']]
```

Comment: tried it on 10k strings and it takes about 1 minute. I would need to run it on millions and that would take very long. is there a way to improve performance? I will always provide a sorted list to the algorithm so the similar strings should be neighbors also

Comment: A good way to improve it would be to reduce the number of subsets originally in `subsets`. Here you can see the subsets are generated in a double for-loop `for l0 in list_list for i in range(len(l0))`: there is one subset per string and per character position in that string. For instance there is one subset for `'*.B.C.D'`, one for `'A.*.C.D'`, one for `'A.B.*.D'`, etc. Some of those subsets are useless, for instance some only contain one element. Perhaps the code could be improved by reducing the number of candidate subsets, if you already know that similar strings are close in the list

Comment: Then if you look at the main while-loop of the algorithm: it contains `max_subset = max(subsets, key=len)` which is an implicit for-loop (finding the maximum is done by iterating). Perhaps this could be improved, for instance by storing the subsets in a heap, a data structure in which it's easy to select the maximum.

Comment: Then there are the "clean-up" operations `universe -= max_subset; subsets.remove(max_subset); subsets = {subset & universe for subset in subsets}` that probably cost some significant time and could be improved somehow.

Comment: @delica One way to generate the subsets if you know that similar strings are close in the list, is to use a sliding window algorithm. Maintain two indices i and j. Initially 0 and 1. At every iteration, increase j by 1. If the sublist [i..j] is a correct subset, then add it to the subsets list. If it is not, then increase i by 1 before adding it to the subsets list.

Comment: true, that sounds like a simple enough solution, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generator function:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def m(a, b):
   return max(map(len, [a - b, b - a])) < 2

def options(l, ind, a):
   for i in a:
      yield '.'.join(l[:ind]+[i]+l[ind+1:])

def groups(d, ch):
   d1, v, last_ind, ind_set = defaultdict(list), [], None, set()
   for i in d:
      d1[i].append(i.split('.'))
   d1 = dict(d1)
   while d1:
      if not v:
         v.extend([(d[0], i) for i in d1.pop(d[0])])
      elif not ind_set:
         k1 = iter(d1)
         while (n:=next(k1)) is not None and not m(set(v[0][-1]), set(n.split('.'))):
            pass
         if n is not None:
             v.extend([(n, i) for i in d1.pop(n)])
             (last_ind, ind_set), *_ = [(i, j) for i, a in enumerate(zip(*[j for _, j in v])) if len((j:=set(a))) != 1]
         else:
             yield [x for x, _ in v]
             n = next(iter(d1))
             v = [(n, i) for i in d1.pop(n)]
             ind_set, last_ind = set(), None
      else:
         if not (o:=[i for i in options(v[0][-1], last_ind, ch[last_ind] - ind_set) if i in d1]):
             yield [x for x, _ in v]
             n = next(iter(d1))
             v = [(n, i) for i in d1.pop(n)]
             ind_set, last_ind = set(), None
         else:
             v.extend([(y, i) for y in o for i in d1.pop(y)])
   yield from ([] if not v else [[x for x, _ in v]])
```

---

```
def get_groups(d):
   ch = list(map(set, zip(*[i.split('.') for i in d])))
   return list(groups(d, ch))

print(get_groups(['A.B.C.D','A.A.C.D','A.B.E.F','A.B.E.GG']))
print(get_groups(["A.B.C", "A.B.D", "A.E.D"]))
print(get_groups(['D.1.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.7.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.21.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.15.6.A.1.B.C', 'D.25.6.A.1.B.C', 'D.7.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.8.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.8.6.A.1.B.C', 'D.10.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.14.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.15.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.15.6.A.1.B.C', 'D.16.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.17.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.18.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.19.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.20.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.21.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.22.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.23.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.25.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.25.6.A.1.B.C', 'D.26.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.27.2.A.1.B.C']))
```

Output:

```
[['A.A.C.D', 'A.B.C.D'], ['A.B.E.F', 'A.B.E.GG']]
[['A.B.C', 'A.B.D'], ['A.E.D']] 
[['D.1.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.7.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.21.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.8.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.10.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.14.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.15.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.16.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.17.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.18.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.19.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.20.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.22.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.23.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.25.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.26.2.A.1.B.C', 'D.27.2.A.1.B.C'], ['D.15.6.A.1.B.C', 'D.25.6.A.1.B.C', 'D.8.6.A.1.B.C']]
```

---

Timings:

```
import string, time
import contextlib, itertools as it
r_s = map('.'.join, it.product(*[string.ascii_uppercase[:10] if not i%2 else string.digits for i in range(6)]))
@contextlib.contextmanager
def timeit(f):
    t = time.time()
    yield 
    print(f'{f} time: {time.time() - t}')

with timeit('groups'):
   _ = [*get_groups([*r_s])]
```

Output:

```
groups time: 43.55898189544678
```

Comment: trying it now on a couple of million strings and it has been running for a while. is there a way to improve performance?

Comment: @delica Please see my recent edit, I added a more efficient solution to handle pre-sorted string input along with timings.

Comment: this is super fast! but I think there is a bug, it seems to skip the first element in each group and put it into a group of it's own. then for next group it skips first 2 and puts them in separate group, then 3, then 4 and so on

Comment: @delica Can you post a small sample of the input that is producing that result, along with the desired output from the sample?

Comment: I added sample input to question. For me that input produces 3 groups, instead of 2. The first 2 groups should be combined. First group is 2 members and second is 15.

Comment: @delica Please see my recent edit. I made some changes so that the solution runs in ~43 seconds on a sample size of one million